# Are all these sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions, as, quantifiers

I have solved that riddle before, so I get **half as much credit as you do**, for solving it.

I have solved that riddle before, so I get **half the credit you do**, for solving it.

I have solved that riddle before, so I get **half the credit as you do**, for solving it.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same thing?

Do we say, "Back in the day, **he made half the money I did**"? Or, do we say "Back in the day, **he made half the money as I did**? Or, ".....**he made half as much money as I did**"?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence uses the "**as much as**" comparative construction correctly. The second is also correct, as it uses "half" as a **predeterminer**. Predeterminers are adjectives or adjectival phrases that come before determiners (articles, demonstratives, possessives, etc.); some examples are **all**, **what**, **twice**, and **both**:

> I eat **all the** food.
>
> **What a** beautiful day!
>
> I pay **twice the** suggested donation.
>
> Do you want **both the** desserts?

The third sentence, however, is incorrect. Since "half" modifies "the credit" directly, you can remove it and see if the resulting sentence is grammatically correct:

> I have solved that riddle before, so I get the credit **as you do**, for solving it.

This is pretty obviously weird and incorrect.

Just FYI, the commas at the end of your sentences before "for" don't need to be there.

**Further reading:**

- [This page on determiners](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/ordering.htm), including predeterminers.
- [Wikipedia on determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)
- [Even more](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm#predeterminers), if you still feel like reading about this